# Slicing up a laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel, performance, controllers

I have a controller in Laravel that handles all operations of an administration panel. At the start, it was working well and all was organized. As I elaborated on it, the controller starting growing drastically in size. For every page in my controller, I dedicate a method to handle the action. Now, my controller is over 1,000 lines and being harder and harder each day to add or edit something. I would like to see the possible ways I can split up this controller into parts, and store these parts like:

```
controllers/
   admin/
      page1.php
      page2.php
      ...
   AdminController.php
   FooController.php
   BarController.php
```

So I can handle each page separately, efficiently. I haven't seen any answers on previous questions on this topic.

Comment: If you're doing MVC then your controllers shouldn't contain any real logic anyway so they shouldn't ever get very big.  All they should do is kick off a use case/business process and assign the results to a view.  Ballooning controllers usually happens when you start putting business logic in them, which is an antipattern known as fat controller.

Comment: I was told that all logic should go in my controllers and to avoid logic in my views. This is my first time using an MVC like Laravel.

Comment: The logic belongs in the models.  That's what the model is, after all.  It's a model of the concepts that your application embodies.

Answer (score 0):

Put your logic in models/service provider instead as makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for taking my comment and turning it into a considerably less helpful answer :)

Comment: I do not think your comment was there prior to my post...but thanks for being snide! :)